# Database Design: Referencing multiple 1 to 0..1 relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a number of different message types (let's say 20) that I need to SELECT based on their date, and their type, in something along the following manner

i.e. `... WHERE date BETWEEN [fromDate] AND [toDate] AND type = [0 - 20 different types]`

The different types of messages have very few columns in common (date being the most important), but I will always need to fetch all kinds of comments "in one go", ordered by date. Messages have a self reference to allow threaded conversations. A message will always be of one type, and only one type.

Because I have 5.000.000 messages in the archive, and rarely more than 50 messages in a conversation, I need to be able to efficiently select by date or a conversation identifier.
Therefore I have a single "mother of all messages"-table and multiple extra tables which have a `1 .. 0-1`relationship to the messages table:

```
messages:   [id, date, parent_id (nullable), ... ]
msgs_type1: [col1, col2, col3, col4, ...]
msgs_type2: [col1, col2, col3, col4, ...]
```

**And then here's my question:** 
How do you normally specify relationships between these types of tables? What are the (dis)advantages of joining the tables in e.g. the following ways:

```
messages: [id, date, parent_id (null), **msg_type_1 (null), msg_type_2 (null)**, ...]
msgs_type1: [col1, col2, col3, col4]
msgs_type2: [col1, col2, col3, col4]
...
```

(Optional relationships specified in messages)

```
messages: [id, date, **type**, parent_id (null)]
msgs_type1: [**message_id**, col1, col2, col3, col4]
msgs_type2: [**message_id**, col1, col2, col3, col4]
...
```

(Mandatory relationships specified in msgs_type tables, lookup table specified in message)

On one hans, it feels dirty to have 20 optional colums, of which (only) one column must have a value in order to specify the type of message.

On the other hand, having a "type" enum column instead, and using it to manually infer what table to look for additional info in also feels wrong - and will probably cause a great deal of pain to work with in most ORMs.

So what does the book say about these types of structures? What about the day I have 200 different types of messages?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO:  Any time you are in a position where you will have to **alter your database** because you've added a new "type" of "something" you are, as they say, *doing it wrong*.  The only time I would be comfortable with this type of column-oriented table is if it were done just before, say, a report was being generated.  Or, perhaps, done at the end of a process to ease work for non-technical users who might want to generate their own queries.

A properly-indexed and normalized table structure with 5 to 10 million rows should still perform just fine.

Comment: I see your point, but in this case, it seems reasonable to alter my database when introducing new types, as these types will always require new individual data (specialized columns for every type).